# Why does ApplyRadialDamageWithFaloff applies full damage?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

For some reason it applies full damage even when actor to damage is further than 100.0f from the MainDamageSphere. What can be the problem? I'm checking for damage with the usage of overriden "TakeDamage" function

**AGrenadePauncherProjectile_CPP::OnHit**

```
void AGrenadeLauncherProjectile_CPP::OnHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp,
                                           FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit)
{
    if (OtherActor != nullptr && OtherActor != this)
    {
        TArray<AActor*> ActorsToIgnore;

        /*UGameplayStatics::ApplyRadialDamageWithFalloff(OtherActor, Damage, 1.0f, Hit.ImpactPoint, 100, 400,
            1.0f, UDamageType::StaticClass(), ActorsToIgnore);*/

        ExplosionClass->Initialize(SplashRadius, 100.0f, Damage, GetTransform(), OtherActor, ActorsToIgnore, this);

        SoundSystem->PlaySoundUnsafe(*ExplosionSoundCue, GetActorLocation());
    }

    Destroy();
}
```

**UExplosion::Initialize**

```
void UExplosion::Initialize(const float& SphereRadiusValue, const float& SphereRadiusValueInner, const float& SplashDamageValue, 
                            const FTransform Transform, AActor* ToDamage, TArray<AActor*> ActorsToIgnore, AActor* ProjectileActor)
{
    if (ExplosionParticleSystem)
    {
        UGameplayStatics::SpawnEmitterAtLocation(GetWorld(), ExplosionParticleSystem, Transform, true, EPSCPoolMethod::None, true);

        // decided to hardcode parameters for debug
        UGameplayStatics::ApplyRadialDamageWithFalloff(ToDamage, SplashDamageValue, 1.0f, Transform.GetLocation(), 100, 400,
                                                       1.0f, UDamageType::StaticClass(), ActorsToIgnore, ProjectileActor);
    }       
}
```

**UPDATE**

As far as I can see from disassembled code, ApplyRadialDamageWithFaloff calls procedure TakeDamage that belongs to my enemy actor(which needs to be damaged) and passes base damage instead of calculating new value relying on enemy's position inside of sphere...
I attach a screenshot of disassembled code where you can see that xmm6 vector register holds a m128_f32 variable that has base damage and it moves it to xmm1(which is a register related to TakeDamage function)

So what's the problem? Why would the main function refuse to calculate new value depending on enemy ator distance from impact point?

[image]

Comment: Sanity check: Which entity/point are you getting the location of with `Transform.GetLocation()`? Docs say that should be the center of the blast.

Comment: @Basic I pass a FTransform of a grenade launcher projectile when it hits something(OnHit). I assume that this is an "end point" for my projectile, so I pass its transform to the ExplosionClass that spawns an explosion emitter and applies radial damage

Comment: @Basic guess I'll provide full code

Comment: I wish I could help but I'm not intimately familiar with UE4, I was just trying to cover some of the low-hanging fruit.

Comment: @Basic never mind, I've already solved the problem. Thank you very much for your attention, pal, I really appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to switch from simple `TakeDamage` to `OnTakeRadialDamage` and `OnTakePointDamage`. The problem was solved.